# How to extract dynamic html content using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract product technical properties. The product could be sometimes electrical, mechanical or others. This is a sample of an electrical product details with technical properties and values

```html
<section>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="message is-primary">
                <header class="message-header">
                    <h4>Technical Characteristics</h4>
                </header>
                <div class="message-body">
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        <dt>ELECTRICAL RESISTANCE</dt>
                        <dd>(AAPP) 3.300 MEGOHMS</dd>
                        <dt>AMBIENT TEMP IN DEG CELSIUS AT FULL RATED POWER</dt>
                        <dd>(AAQF) 70.0</dd>
                         <dt>RESISTANCE TOLERANCE IN PERCENT</dt>
                        <dd>(AAPQ) -5.000/+5.000</dd><dt>POWER DISSIPATION RATING IN WATTS</dt>
                        <dd>(AEFB) 0.250 FREE AIR</dd><dt>STYLE DESIGNATOR</dt>
        
                        <dd>(TEST) 81349-MIL-R-11/8 SPECIFICATION (INCLUDES ENGINEERINGIONS THAT ARE SHOWN AS "TYPICAL", "AVERAGE", "NOMINAL", ETC.).</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I can use this python script to extract the electrical property keys and values

```
productsoup = BeautifulSoup(productdriver.page_source,"lxml");

try:

   for li in productsoup.find_all('dt',text=re.compile('^(ELECTRICAL RESISTANCE)|^(AMBIENT TEMP)|^(RESISTANCE TOLERANCE)|^(DISSIPATION)')):
```

but sometimes the mechanical product could have this format

```html
<section>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="message is-primary">
                <header class="message-header">
                    <h4>Technical Characteristics</h4>
                </header>
                <div class="message-body">
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        <dt>END ITEM IDENTIFICATION</dt>
                        <dd>(AGAV) END ITEM 6675014301965</dd><dt>BODY STYLE</dt>
                        <dd>(AAQL) TUBE TYPE</dd><dt>CONTINUOUS CURRENT RATING IN AMPS</dt>
                        <dd>(AEBJ) 1.600</dd><dt>III END ITEM IDENTIFICATION</dt>
                        <dd>(AGAV) END ITEM 6675014301965</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How do I extract what the technical properties (`dt`) and corresponding values are (`dd`)?

Comment: This is kind of why web scraping is a bitch. Is everything always in a dl tag? You could just pull the dl tag and make a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<section>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="message is-primary">
                <header class="message-header">
                    <h4>Technical Characteristics</h4>
                </header>
                <div class="message-body">
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        <dt>END ITEM IDENTIFICATION</dt>
                        <dd>(AGAV) END ITEM 6675014301965</dd>
                        <dt>BODY STYLE</dt>
                        <dd>(AAQL) TUBE TYPE</dd>
                        <dt>CONTINUOUS CURRENT RATING IN AMPS</dt>
                        <dd>(AEBJ) 1.600</dd>
                        <dt>III END ITEM IDENTIFICATION</dt>
                        <dd>(AGAV) END ITEM 6675014301965</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
dts = soup.find_all("dt")
outs = {i.string: i.find_next("dd").string for i in dts}
print(outs)
#> {'END ITEM IDENTIFICATION': '(AGAV) END ITEM 6675014301965', 'BODY STYLE': '(AAQL) TUBE TYPE', 'CONTINUOUS CURRENT RATING IN AMPS': '(AEBJ) 1.600', 'III END ITEM IDENTIFICATION': '(AGAV) END ITEM 6675014301965'}
```

Created on 2018-09-28 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)

```py
import reprexpy
print(reprexpy.SessionInfo())
#> Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Platform: Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit (64-bit)
#> Python: 3.6
#> Date: 2018-09-28
#> Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
#> reprexpy==0.1.1
```